# Calling function inside a directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

Sorry If this question has been asked before, but my issue is bit different and hope someone can help me out.

1) I have a Directive which has many buttons. I want to call a function on this buttons and inside a directive. But I don't know how.

```
// Directive for the login header to avoid the duplication of the code
angular.module('App').directive('mainHeader',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'AE',
        template:'<h1 class="logo"> My App  </h1>'+
        '<button class="btn btn-primary">New User</button>'+
        '<button class="btn btn-primary">New Product</button>'+

            '<span class="dropdown" on-toggle="toggled(open)">'+
                '<a href class="dropdown-toggle">'+
                '<img class="userProfile" src="" alt="User Profile">'+
                '<b class="caret"></b>'+
               '</a>'+
                    // Here on my profile ????
                '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">'+
                    '<li> My Profile </a> </li>'+
                    '<li class="divider"></li>'+
                       // Here on my logout ?????? 
                       // This does not work
                    '<li> <a href="" ng-click="logOut()"> Sign Out </li>'+
                '</ul>'+
            '</span>'
    }
});
```

My controller

```
(function() {
    var logOutController = function($scope){
      $scope.logOut = function(){
           // Want to call this
        }
    logOutController .$inject = ['$scope'];
    angular.module('App').controller('logOutController ',logOutController );
}());
```

And my view will be only one line

```
<div main-header></div>
```

I don't know how to do this

Update 1: -

Please have a look at the Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/YONVyVvNm4pQGFMU6SkG?p=preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will just need to add an isolate scope to your directive:

```
// Directive for the login header to avoid the duplication of the code
angular.module('App').directive('mainHeader', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '<h1 class="logo"> My App  </h1>' +
        '<button class="btn btn-primary">New User</button>' +
        '<button class="btn btn-primary">New Product</button>' +

        '<span class="dropdown" on-toggle="toggled(open)">' +
        '<a href class="dropdown-toggle">' +
        '<img class="userProfile" src="" alt="User Profile">' +
        '<b class="caret"></b>' +
        '</a>' +
            // Here on my profile ????
        '<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">' +
        '<li> My Profile </a> </li>' +
        '<li class="divider"></li>' +
            // Here on my logout ?????? 
            // This does not work
        '<li> <a href="" ng-click="logOut()"> Sign Out </li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</span>',
        scope: {
            'logOut': '&onLogOut' //<- this ties your directive's logOut function to an attr on the HTML tag
        }
    }
});
```

Then you just modify your HTML to:

```
<div main-header on-log-out="logOut()"></div>
```

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MXoFqe2zrkPqZCq3xRCg?p=preview)

Comment: That's the thing, but what about other buttons? which has click on it ? and its on the same directive

Comment: Oops sorry about that, I didn't see that. Is the `dropdown` another directive? You will need to show the rest of the code for `mainHeader` to really tell. However it should be a similar approach.

Comment: Nope everything on same directive. And inside this directive are buttons and I want to call different function on this buttons. So no duplication of code.

Comment: Sorry but this does not work. And I am not after this

Comment: @GeekOnGadgets Is it possible to create a jsfiddle or plunker to show what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GeekOnGadgets Is the `mainHeader` directive used anywhere else? Directives are mainly used when you need to reuse functionality in multiple places. It looks like what you want to do is put it directly in the HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64447/discussion-between-esteban-felix-and-geekongadgets).